# Из-за чего может быть не виден сайт из интернета по https

Tags: https, ssl

У меня из внутренней сети сайт работает корректно по https, а вот из интернета его не видно. Сайт начинает бесконечно загружаться и всё. 
По http сайт работает из интернета и из сети.

В чем могут быть причины?

Comment: Фаервол, http и https используют разные порты, скорей всего у вас во вне не проброшен 443 порт.

Comment: 80 vs 443: https://isc.sans.edu/diary/Cyber+Security+Awareness+Month+-+Day+25+-+Port+80+and+443/7450

Comment: @RifmaMan,. А вы можете посмотреть вот этот вопрос там более детально описано https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/843188/https-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-connection-timeout

Comment: >>а вот из интернета его не видно<< Такая же проблема была когда зарубили амазоновские подсети (если вы из РФ). Если не сомневаетесь в правильности своего фаервола - проверьте доступ к сайту по домену, и по апишнику, на всякий случай. Для сравнения, у меня не работал даже google.com по https...

Comment: @test123 А вы можете посмотреть вот этот вопрос там более детально описано https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/843188/https-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-connection-timeout

Comment: @RifmaMan вот что показывает netstat -ltpn на сервере tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      18544/nginx -g daem

Comment: @RifmaMan , это нормально что там нолики вместо ip сервера? Это значит что порт не проброшен наружу?

Comment: @Dmitriy с настройкой веб сервера и фаервола на linux к сожалению вам не подскажу, все нули перед портом говорят о том, что правило присваивается ко всем адресам на сервере.

Comment: Нолики -это означает, что сервис «слушает» на всех доступных в ОС сетевых интерфейсах. Ваш вопрос скорее всего в настройке DNAT на вашем фаерволе.

Comment: @de_frag я разобрался , действительно 443 порт не был проброшен наружу.